# When using conditional statements inside of forEach, how to detect if every child failed the condition?

Tags: javascript, foreach, conditional-statements, firebase

Starting with a Firebase [DataSnapshot](http://www.firebase.com/docs/datasnapshot.html), I want something so that, in plain English, "if all the children failed the condition, execute something".

Here is what I have now:

```
     appleappsRef.on('value', function (allApplesSnapshot){
            allApplesSnapshot.forEach(function (appleSnapshot) {
                if (condition) {
                   //execute code
                } 
            });             
      });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per [the docs](http://www.firebase.com/docs/datasnapshot/foreach.html), your forEach callback can return true to cancel enumeration and forEach() will return true to signal that enumeration was canceled.

This means you can do:

```
appleappsRef.on('value', function (allApplesSnapshot){
  var foundOne = allApplesSnapshot.forEach(function (appleSnapshot) {
    if (condition) {
       return true; // found one, cancel enumeration
    }
  });
  if (!foundOne) {
    // all children failed the condition.
  }
});
```

Comment: this is actually pretty cool.... I did not know how to escape a forEach and this helps instead using promises or async

Comment: There is no way to stop or break a forEach() loop other than by throwing an exception. If you need such behavior, the forEach() method is the wrong tool, use a plain loop instead. If you are testing the array elements for a predicate and need a Boolean return value, you can use every() or some() instead.

Answer (score 2):

```
if (allApplesSnapshot.every(function (appleSnapshot) { return !condition; }))
    // ...
```

[`Array.every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) returns `true` if every element of the array satisfies the function you pass it (that is, the function returns true when passed that element). So to test if every element *fails* a condition, then simply negate the condition within the function.

Note that some browsers don't [support](http://kangax.github.com/es5-compat-table/) `Array.every`, but every browser that supports `Array.forEach` should also support `Array.every`.

Comment: Casey, thank you for this. With //... , do you mean {code executed} ? Thanks.

Comment: That's the code you want to execute if every element fails the condition. Am I understanding your question correctly? Do you want to execute something if an element passes the condition and *then* something else if everything fails the condition?

Comment: For each item in the Array, test condition X. If condition X is true, execute code A for that item. If all items return false, then execute code B. Thanks. I'm still learning so I appreciate your help.

Comment: Ah. In that case, take a look at @jfriend00's answer.

Comment: Even if this was the desired behavior, it won't work.  DataSnapshot has no .every() method. http://www.firebase.com/docs/datasnapshot.html

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with .forEach using a boolean to keep track if you ever found the condition to be true:

```
 appleappsRef.on('value', function (allApplesSnapshot){
        var foundOne = false;
        allApplesSnapshot.forEach(function (appleSnapshot) {
            if (condition) {
               foundOne = true;
            } 
        });             
        if (!foundOne) {
            // all children failed the condition
        }
  });
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this. I chose the second one. Very elegant.

Comment: The first solution won't work at all.  DataSnapshot has no .length.  http://www.firebase.com/docs/datasnapshot.html

Comment: @MichaelLehenbauer - OK, we were all guessing here what allApplesSnapshot was as the OP provided no info on its type.  I thought it was an array.  I guess not.  I removed the first option.

Comment: There is no way to stop or break a forEach() loop other than by throwing an exception. If you need such behavior, the forEach() method is the wrong tool, use a plain loop instead. If you are testing the array elements for a predicate and need a Boolean return value, you can use every() or some() instead.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could always loop through it and at any moment one of the children passes break out of the method somehow, otherwise fire the method that should be fired when all children fail. You can even use a boolean in this case.

Ex: Make a boolean and call it allChildrenFailed and set it to true by default. Go through the foreach loop, and if any child passes change it to false. Then fire the method you need after the loop only if allChildrenFailed is true.